# Trouble patching a function of a function

Tags: python, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm pretty new to patching and I've run into a something I don't know how to patch. Basically, in the file I want to test, there is the method `difficult_method()`. It looks a little like this:

```
from import_location import User

def difficult_method():
  ids = list_of_ids
  for id in list_of_ids:
    try:
      user = User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).all()[0]
    except:
      continue
    #do lots of stuff
```

The code I want to mock is `User.query.filter(User.id == user_id).all()` and as far as I am concerned it can return a static list. How would I replace that line in code that looks something like this:

```
from mock import patch

@patch(#what would go here?)
def test_difficult_method(): 
  from file_to_test import difficult_method
  assert difficult_method() returns ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The key was to create a MockUser class, like so:

```
user = #creating a user

class MockFilter(object):
  def all(self):
    return [user]


class MockQuery(object):

  def filter(self, match):
    return MockFilter()


class MockUser(object):
  query = MockQuery()
  id = '2'
```

Then I patched it in like so:

```
from mock import patch

@patch('import_location.User', MockUser)
def test_difficult_method(): 
  from file_to_test import difficult_method
  assert difficult_method() returns ...
```